# Stuck in Trigger Test Class

Tags: unit-test

[image]

Not able to cover the else block.Below is the test Class

```
@isTest
public class TestConTrigg 
{
    static testmethod void testFun()
    {
        account acc = new account();
        acc.name ='less';
        insert acc;

        contact con = new contact();
        con.lastname = 'ram';
        con.password__c = 'sdaf';
        con.Accountid = acc.Id;
        insert con;

        account acc1 = new account();
        acc1.name =' ';
        insert acc1;

        contact con1 = new contact();
        con1.Accountid = acc1.Id;
        con1.lastname = acc1.name;
        con1.password__c = 'sdaqwe';
        update con1;
    }    
}
```

Comment: your trigger isn't firing on before or after delete. Delete the contact in the test class too.

Comment: hey add after delete or before delete event in trigger

Answer (score 3):

Add  for `delete` statement for `Contact`:

```
static testmethod void testFun()
{
    account acc = new account();
    acc.name ='less';
    insert acc;

    contact con = new contact();
    con.lastname = 'ram';
    con.password__c = 'sdaf';
    con.Accountid = acc.Id;
    insert con;

    account acc1 = new account();
    acc1.name =' ';
    insert acc1;

    contact con1 = new contact();
    con1.Accountid = acc1.Id;
    con1.lastname = acc1.name;
    con1.password__c = 'sdaqwe';
    update con1;

    delete con1; // Thats all!
}
```

Also add following conditions in `else if(Trigger.isDelete)` and `after delete event` also. This will prevent double execution.

```
trigger AcoountName on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    // Few things here exist..
    else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete)
    {
       // Run!
    }  
}
```

Comment: Also He needs to add delete event in trigger

Comment: Hey Can you explain in detail i didnt got you.